# How to save as Webp file in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-format

I was working on application design in Photoshop and here we need a webp file. How do I save or export from Photoshop as webp?

Comment: You may be able to use a web service. Just search webp to jpg or jpg to webp conversion tool.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Photoshop doesn't have it added to its program on the go. That meaning you'll have to download a plugin in order to export to webp formats.

You can find the plugin for Photoshop here:
https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/webpshop

As soon as this is installed you should be able to save/export to the extension.

Answer (score 1):

You can find free plugins for Photoshop here (select the appropriate platform):

http://telegraphics.com.au/sw/product/WebPFormat#webpformat

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but the accepted answer goes to a link and that tutorial is not very clear.

**Windows installation steps**

1. Download the latest `ZIP source file` (do not download the script only)
   from: https://github.com/webmproject/WebPShop/releases
2. Copy the plug-in file WebPShop.8bi located in the zip file,  `bin\WebPShop_0_3_0_Win_x64` to the Photoshop installation folder, usually `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop\Plug-ins` for x64.
3. Restart Photoshop. "Open" and "Save" menu commands should now show WebP files.

Recommended options: slowlest compression and more than 80% of quality, preview enabled.

Comment: There is no WebPShop.8bi in WebPShop-0.3.2.zip

Comment: @Jon My answer is for _0_3_0, i'ts specific in the point 2. Please read careful. I can't update my answer for every update in the solution, I'm not the owner of the code. Please read the S.O. guidelines and tutorial. Thanks.