# How to work with this peculiar kind of JPEG? (Invalid JPEG marker type)

Tags: file-format, image-format, file-conversion, jpeg, webp

Today I was reading [an article online](https://www.wired.com/story/zoom-backlash-zero-days/) and while looking at the photo accompanying it I noticed some chromatic aberration that I found interesting (wanted to figure out  if it was a camera artifact or added as a post effect), so I decided to take a closer look in Photoshop.

[image]

However, when I tried to open it, I got this error:

### Could not open “Security_zoom_1137878047.jpg” because an unknown or invalid JPEG marker type is found.

[Here is the original photo.](https://media.wired.com/photos/5e83d83eff7da9000915c630/master/w_2560%2Cc_limit/Security_zoom_1137878047.jpg)

In this particular case I don't need to edit the photo, and if I did I could always just take a screen shot (as I did of the 'H' above). But it got me thinking maybe I should learn how to work with these kinds of images, and maybe even learn how to make them.

When opened in TextEdit the file begins with this:

[image]

So, finding it odd that web browsers can display this file but an image editor can't, I did some searching and found a page that offered some clues. The page is titled **Viewing a WEBPVP8 image in a RIFF file** (it is not http**s**:// so I'm not linking to it, but you can find it with a search engine). Although the gist of it is: It's a WEBPVP8 image (is that the same as WebP?) and it can be opened in a browser, but not Photoshop.

Also, as a test I converted this image to a regular JPEG using https://ezgif.com/webp-to-jpg

The resulting file can be opened by Photoshop.

Now knowing I can convert and open such files, my remaining questions are:

1. What kind of file is this really, JPEG or WebP with a .jpg extension?
2. Under what circumstances would someone save a file in this format?
3. How would one save a file in this format?

Comment: You shoudl probably convert webp to png if your purpose was to edit it,

Comment: @joojaa In this case I'm not going to edit the photo. But yes, PNG would be better than JPEG if editing. I'm just trying to find out what's up with this strange .jpg that acts like a .webp and needs to be converted to a "proper" .jpg before Ps will handle it. All the article images on [WIRED](https://www.wired.com/) currently use this format. I'm sure there's a good reason, but I don't know what that reason is.

Comment: the file ending is just text in the name. Anybody can write anything they like in the file ending, Its simply a WebP image. Nothing stops me renaming jpegs as txt or webp as jpeg. Probably this was done to expedite teh use of webp so they wouldnt need to reconfigure their server.

Comment: @joojaa That theory makes sense. To test it I changed the .jpg extension to .webp - interestingly, Chrome will open it but Firefox will not (although Firefox also supports WebP). This makes me suspect it *wasn't* originally a .webp and Chrome is just less strict about extensions and header info matching up. Mysteries...

Comment: Also there are useful reasons to alter ending, reading software often do not recognize the files by the ending but read the binary header instead, so they dont care.  But the OS does so if you want to pair a image with a second set of software than usual then you can just alter the ending.

Comment: that makes sense firefox supports webp only if the server does.

Comment: @joojaa Wait, when I try **Open With** from Finder Firefox is greyed out as an option and will not accept the file. *However* if I place the image in an HTML file and that webpage calls the image, it will display! Mystery solved. It looks like you were spot-on. Thanks for satisfying my curiosity. (I'll accept an answer if you care to post one.) I think it might even be macOS that refuses to let Firefox try to open it.

Comment: Hmmm.... the webp image opens first time in GIMP 2.10.18.  I suppose you may need a plugin to open it directly in Photoshop.  Seems to be [one here](https://github.com/webmproject/WebPShop), but I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File ending is just metadata in the filename. Nobody is forced to use the file ending that corresponds with file type. In fact there are lots of lesser known file endings that have several applications that want to associate themselves with the ending.*

**(1)** This file is a WebP image. Applications that support the file often do not care of the ending they will just read the header to determine what the file is. However the operating system may disagree with you. The probable reason is that somebody wanted to avoid changing metadata in their server.

This can be extremely useful, I use it for EPS files all the time. What I do is call them epsX files and that type is associated with a script launcher. This allows me to embed the image in adobe software. But when i ask to edit the file it does not open it in illustrator (even in illustrator) but a custom dialog tailored for that file.. SO i can make custom GUIS for files but still use it as a EPS at the same time.

* Also you'd be surprised how many file formats are just zip files.

<sub>Edit by [Mentalist](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/21178/):</sub>

**(2)** Now knowing this is a WebP file, a reason one might choose to save in that format is:

> Google claims that webp reduces the size of images significantly in
>   comparison to png and jpg. It reduces the file size in comparison to
>   png images by up to 26%, and by up to 34% in comparison to jpg images.
>   [Source](https://www.ghacks.net/2013/10/15/avoid-saving-images-webp-format-google-chrome/)

[Browser support for WebP](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp)

**(3)** [Here's](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/100467/21178) how to save a WebP file using Photoshop (with a plugin). There are also web applications (such as [this one](https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-webp)) that can convert images to WebP from other formats.

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! I added a couple of points to directly address those that I mentioned in my question. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the first time that I've run into a WebP or RIFF8 image file. The posts here were informative.

What I did is open the file in Chrome, then Print that to a PDF. Then I opened the PDF in Photoshop, choosing to open the Images, rather than the page. It retained the layer (clear background).

Then I saved that as a PNG.